# Specifiy the URL where model data can be found

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have these models:

```
App.Profile = DS.Model.extend({
    name  : DS.attr('string'),
    type  : DS.attr('string')
});

App.User = App.Profile.extend({
    email : DS.attr('string')
});

App.Company = App.Profile.extend({
    vat : DS.attr('string')
});

App.Profile.FIXTURES = [
    { id: 'me',         type: 'user'   , name: 'Max Smith',        email: 'max.smith@email.com'},
    { id: 'my-company', type: 'company', name: 'Good Company Inc', vat: 'B456DF' },
];
```

The data for both `User` and `Company` is to be found in the `Profile` `FIXTURE`. How can I configure the `User` and `Company` models to use that common `FIXTURE`? This would *not* do:

```
App.User.FIXTURES = App.Profile.FIXTURES;
```

Because I want to really have a single and common endpoint, not to fake it duplicating the fixtures.

My real goal is to be able to access the backend for both `User` and `Company` objects in the same URL: `/api/profile`; if somebody can clarify this, the `FIXTURE` question is secondary (I am just interested in it in order to have this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/uCUboCo/6/) working)

### EDIT

For `ember-data` it is possible to configure the [API global endpoint](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_endpoint-path-customization) and the [model pluralization](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_pluralization-customization). But what I want to configure is where to find each of the models in the global api namespace. That is, I do not want `ember-data` to infer the API endpoint based on the model name, but I want to explicitly configure it.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think that in the moment ember-data doesn't have that option, so my sugestion is to use  [ember model](https://github.com/ebryn/ember-model) because is more flexible, and you can configure a adapter per class.

```
App.Profile = Ember.Model.extend({
    name  : Ember.attr(),
    type  : Ember.attr()
});

App.User = Ember.Profile.extend({
    email : Ember.attr()
});

// when using fixtures
App.User.adapter = Ember.FixtureAdapter.create();

// or when using rest adapter
App.User.url = '/api/profile';
App.User.adapter = Ember.RESTAdapter.create();

App.Company = Ember.Profile.extend({
    vat : Ember.attr()
});

// when using fixtures
App.Company.adapter = Ember.FixtureAdapter.create();

// or when using rest adapter
App.Company.url = '/api/profile';
App.Company.adapter = Ember.RESTAdapter.create();

// When using fixtures
// I think that this cannot be avoided
App.User.FIXTURES = App.Company  = [
    { id: 'me',         type: 'user'   , name: 'Max Smith',        email: 'max.smith@email.com'},
    { id: 'my-company', type: 'company', name: 'Good Company Inc', vat: 'B456DF' },
];
```